# How to call latexmk in emacs, and jump to next-error

Tags: emacs, latex, build-process, auctex, latexmk

I would like to use [latexmk](http://www.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/) to compile my LaTeX documents in Emacs. Especially I need the Emacs functionality `next-error`, which is typically called with C-x `, and jumps to the next LaTeX error in the document.

I would like to call `latexmk` either using `C-x compile` or the AUCTeX `C-c C-c`.

First, I set `latexmk` to use

```
$pdflatex = 'pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode';
```

**Option 1: C-x compile**

I press `C-x compile` and type `latexmk -pdf foo`, which runs `pdflatex`. But `next-error` will not jump to the errors, even if the *compilation* buffer contains errors:

```
! Paragraph ended before \author was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.48 
[...]
Compilation exited abnormally with code 12
```

How can I automatically jump to this error in line 48?

Note that this question of parsing the latex output has nothing to do with `latexmk` directly. The same problem occurs when I just do `C-x compile pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode foo`.

**Option 2: AUCTeX**

How can I set AUCTeX to call `latexmk -pdf` instead of `pdflatex` on my .tex file? Of course, I want `next-error` to work here too.

**UPDATE:** I started a **bounty** because if this worked it would be a great tool for many people. I consider the question answered if a solution is given that lets me easily compile my LaTeX document using `latexmk` in Emacs and jump to the errors using `next-error` (of course, the errors might be in *included* .tex files, not necessarily in the master file or the current buffer).

**UPDATE:** Thanks to Ivan (and Chris) for making AUCTeX+Latexmk work. In the meantime, I found that using [Rubber](https://launchpad.net/rubber/) to compile LaTeX is also an excellent choice. It will display error messages in the format used by `gcc` and other compilers, so it naturally works with Emacs `C-x compile`, e.g. `C-x compile rubber --pdf foo`, and the error messages are parsed correctly.

Comment: See also this remotely related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738755/dont-make-me.

Comment: There is also `TeX-run-compile` so that you can use the AucTeX interface to kick of the compile process.  Try `C-h v TeX-command-list RET` to see the full list of different methods available.

Comment: See also https://github.com/tom-tan/auctex-latexmk, available through Emacs package managers (not sure on which repo).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Sorry I don't have the ability to comment, or I would just add this as a comment.  Chris Conway's answer works, except that it should use `TeX-run-TeX` instead of `TeX-run-command` so that AucTeX knows to process the error messages.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push 
    '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run Latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
```

It might also be wise to add something like

```
'("%(-PDF)"
  (lambda ()
    (if (and (not TeX-Omega-mode)
             (or TeX-PDF-mode TeX-DVI-via-PDFTeX))
        "-pdf" "")))
```

to `TeX-expand-list` and use `"latexmk %(-PDF) %s"` so that it will work in both pdf and dvi mode.  Personally, I find it easier to use customize especially when you are experimenting.

Comment: If your comments get 250 bounties, your answers must be superb! =)

Comment: Oh, they are superb. :)

Answer (score 9):

It's relatively easy to get AucTeX to run latexmk with `C-c C-c`. The following will add a `Latexmk` choice to the list of TeX commands:

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push 
    '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %s" TeX-run-command nil t 
      :help "Run Latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
```

The trick is getting `next-error` to work. If you dig around in the AucTeX sources, you can probably find the regex it uses on TeX output buffers; it's not automatically applied to the buffer created by TeX-run-command. (You might also be able to convince `compile` mode to use this regex.)

Another approach is to redefine the variable `LaTeX-command`. This is a bit iffy because I think a lot of AucTeX functions assume they can tack command-line options onto this string and execute the result.

Comment: Wow thanks for this nice bit of code I was having a maddening problem that i couldn't fix and somehow this snippet made everything work. +1

Answer (score 3):

Adding %(mode) gives latexmk some more options like noninteractive if it is set so in auctex.

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (push 
    '("Latexmk" "latexmk -pdf %(mode) %s" TeX-run-TeX nil t
      :help "Run Latexmk on file")
    TeX-command-list)))
```